# Correct way of submitting a job to YARN cluster in which job has dependencies on external jars?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to understand on what is the correct way of submitting a MR (for that matter a Spark based Java) job to YARN cluster.

Consider the situation below:

Using client machine develop code (MR or Spark) jobs, and say the codes uses 3rd party jar's. Now, when a developer has to submit the job to the YARN cluster, what is the correct way of submitting the job to cluster so that there is no run time exception of class not found. Since job is submitted as jar file, how can a developer "put" the 3rd party jars?

I am having difficulty in understanding this, can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to simply build a "fat jar," with Gradle or Maven, that contains not only your compiled code but also all transitive dependencies.

You can use either the [Maven Assembly Plugin](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/) or any of the Gradle plugins like the [Shadow Plugin](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/).

The output of these is what you should supply to `spark-submit`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this what is called as "uber jar"? So, can a jar have jar within it? Does it package "dependencies" class or jar?

Comment: Yes, Uber Jar is fancy term of saying a fat jar.

Comment: Yes, "uber jar" is another term for a "fat jar." And no, everything needs to be exploded--unless you want to write messy custom `ClassLoader` code, which you really don't want to do.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. So if we don't want a "fat" jar, then it is the cluster which has to provide the dependencies?  Do you have any "best practice" pointers how things work in real production cluster where complex problems are being solved?

Comment: The complexity of the problem isn't the issue; in fact, I'm sure most people would consider their data science problems "complex." The issue is how to put your dependencies in the classpath so the JVM will load them. That's true whether you have 10 classes or 100. I'm not sure what's so bad about a fat jar outside of the potential need to shade; I find it very reliable. But you can always put your dependencies somewhere and use `spark.jars` (as described [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)) or another configuration if you want.

Comment: Thanks so much for your info, helped to clarify things.